# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/Pool

Tags: java, bash

When running a script i have encountered this error :

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/istack/Pool
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1126)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:441)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.utils.DataSourceUtils.loadJAXBConfiguration(DataSourceUtils.java:344)
at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceManager.initDataSource(DataSourceManager.java:159)
at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceManager.initDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:137)
at org.wso2.carbon.datasource.core.DataSourceManager.initDataSources(DataSourceManager.java:109)
at org.wso2.carbon.privacy.forgetme.sql.instructions.DatasourceProcessorConfigReader.readProcessorConfig(DatasourceProcessorConfigReader.java:45)
at org.wso2.carbon.privacy.forgetme.sql.instructions.DatasourceProcessorConfigReader.readProcessorConfig(DatasourceProcessorConfigReader.java:32)
at org.wso2.carbon.privacy.forgetme.ConfigReader.loadExtensions(ConfigReader.java:213)
at org.wso2.carbon.privacy.forgetme.ConfigReader.readSystemConfig(ConfigReader.java:112)
at org.wso2.carbon.privacy.forgetme.ForgetMeTool.process(ForgetMeTool.java:201)
at org.wso2.carbon.privacy.forgetme.ForgetMeTool.main(ForgetMeTool.java:141)
```

jaxb-core and jaxb-impl jars  are properly added in the project.

Comment: which version(s)?

Comment: jaxb-impl 2.27 and jaxb-core 2.30

Comment: I think that's your problem. the later versions of jaxb-impl no longer seem to contain that class, so you'll need to add a dependency to the com.sun.istack libraries you need yourself

Comment: Thanks ! I jaxb-impl 2.2 and this error resolved.  It contains com.sun.istack.Pool.class                                http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaxbimpl22jar.htm

Comment: why going back to an old version? Just add a dependency to the com.sun.istack libraries. Usually, going back to an older version isn't really a good solution.

Comment: Done . Added the dependency for  com.sun.istack and it is working fine.

Comment: The Maven coordinates are `com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.11` in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The jaxb-core is depending on the istack-commons-runtime, which can be found in the pom of the jaxb-core. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime)

Comment: the class that can't be found should also be in the jaxb-impl jar

Comment: I prefer to add `jaxb-core` as a dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core